# How do I add Hyperlinks to the "Related Work" field on details page of azure devops work item?

Tags: azure-devops

On the details screen of my Azure DevOps work item there is a "Related Work" field:

[image: Related Work]

But I can't seem to add Hyperlinks through the Add Link > Existing item option:

[image: Hyperlink doesn't show up as a link type]

Instead, to add a hyperlink, I have to go to the Links tab, then Add Link > Existing item.  Through this route, Hyperlink does show up:

[image: Links Tab]
[image: Hyperlink shows up as a link type]

But this route unfortunately takes people away from the main details page and these hyperlinks never show up on the main details page.

How can I allow my users to add a hyperlink from the main "Related Links" field on the details page?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no build-in feature to display Hyperlink on the work item "Details" page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops

Only the following types are supported on the "Details" page.

[image]

Hyperlink could be added to the "Links" page.

[image]

If you need this feature to be supported in Azure DevOps, you could create a request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion